# Displaying datetime in view in datepicker

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my mvc application I've got a datepicker control and this control doesn't read value from database.

Model:

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd'.'MM'.'yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public DateTime? myDate { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px; margin-top: 15px;">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.myDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.myDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker", @type = "date" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.myDate , "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
```

Value in model: 
model.myDate.Date {14.02.2019 0:00:00}

On the view it's displaying

dd.mm.yyyy without any values.

Saving works fine though.

Comment: Can you try to use anchor tags like this: `<label asp-for="myDate" value="@Model.myDate.ToShortDateString()" class="control-label col-md-4" />` or just `<label asp-for="myDate" class="control-label col-md-4" />`

Comment: but would it be still datepicker?

Comment: try my friend :) but what I posted before is just an updated replacement of your Html.LabelFor tag, so I think it still will be. And I assume you see your date in your label, right?

Comment: "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions." on the line with @Html.EditFor  when I replaced the label

Comment: With or without the Value property in the label? try both please

Comment: sometimes it could be the browser  you using. Its worth trying on different browser

Comment: The value you assign to the model.myDate should be like this
model.myDate='2019-01-20'

Comment: Is it necessary to use this : `DataFormatString = "{0:dd'.'MM'.'yyyy}"` and not this  `DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}"` ? I might be missing something

Answer (score 0):

My co-worker solved the problem by editing View in this way:

```
 <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px; margin-top: 15px;">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.myDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.myDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = (@Model.myDate.HasValue ? @Model.myDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : null), @class = "form-control datepicker", @type = "date" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.myDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be in the `DataFormatString`.

Try replacing:

```
DataFormatString = "{0:dd'.'MM'.'yyyy}"
```

with this:

```
DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}"
```